# Can't Upgrade from 22.04 to 22.10?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I'm currently trying to upgrade from 22.04 to 22.10 (just because I'd like to), and for some reason, I have 20 packages that no matter what I try, they will not update, which is holding me back from upgrading. I've tried everything it says to update them, delete them, etc. and nothing. Any advice?

When I run `sudo apt update`, I get this result:

```
    Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
    Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
    Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                 
    Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
    Hit:5 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/ InRelease     
    Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]  
    Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
    Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [41.4 kB]
     Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [102 kB]
    Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [13.3 kB]
    Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [265 kB]
    Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
    Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [12.5 kB]
    Fetched 759 kB in 1s (540 kB/s)                                               
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    20 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
    W: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/focal-cran40/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libinput-bin libinput10 python3-software-properties r-base r-base-core
  r-base-dev r-cran-class r-cran-cluster r-cran-foreign r-cran-lattice
  r-cran-mass r-cran-matrix r-cran-mgcv r-cran-nlme r-cran-nnet r-cran-rpart
  r-recommended software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
  ubuntu-advantage-tools
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
```

When I run `sudo do-release-upgrade`, I get this:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

Any advice would be wonderful.

Thanks!

EDIT:
After running `sudo apt install packagename` I get this:

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     r-base-core : Depends: libicu66 (>= 66.1-1~) but it is not installable
     E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please look for phased updates.

Comment: I've updated my post to where it specifies everything, as user535733 has asked.

Comment: The output of these re-formatted as "code" to make them readable.

Comment: You mention running `apt upgrade`, have you run `apt full-upgrade` as there are cases where upgrade cannot install all upgrades as is documented (read `man apt` or if you prefer `man apt-get` where the older command is `apt-get dist-upgrade`).  Next is to check you didn't put the holds on those packages  (`apt-mark showhold` etc)

Comment: Right, my bad, I'm on it!

Comment: @Nmath I just tried that exact thing and it says that I "have held broken packages."

Comment: I didn't think I had changed any interpreters, is there any way to fix that if I did? And I will do that shortly.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look and see if you can locate the problem.

1. You're running a 22.04 ("jammy") system
2. You have a source that says `https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/`

See it? "focal" instead of "jammy"

You are running R packages that are for the wrong release of Ubuntu AND from a non-Ubuntu source. Double-whammy. That's why they are "kept back". That's why you are seeing the "impossible situation" paragraph.

1. Preserve your data.
2. Uninstall ALL R packages from that wrong-version source. (`https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu focal-cran40/`)
3. Disable or delete that source.
4. Run `sudo apt update` because you just changed your sources.
5. Run `sudo apt clean` to remove those wrong-version packages from your local cache.
6. Re-install the R packages. Without that wrong-version source, your system will install them from the compatible Ubuntu repositories.

This should solve most of your problems.